# What is the main difference between these two SSDs?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I'm wondering what's the biggest difference between the `KC300` and `V300` SSDs by Kingston. By looking at the specs for each I can't find much difference:

[KC300](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/skc300s3_en.pdf)

[V300](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/sv300s3_en.pdf)

Which one is newer and/or recommended over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the specifications I would expect the KC300 to be slightly newer/better.

The "total bytes written" specification at 60GB disk size is 32TB for the V300 and 47TB for the KC300 which suggest that the wear leveller on the KC300 drive performs better.

Also the "Maximum random 4k read/write" and "sequential read/write" specifications for the KC300 are slightly higher.

To me the KC300 looks better/newer.